# How to modify `sql_mode` using the configuration file in TiDB?

Tags: distributed-database, tidb

I want to modify the `sql_mode` of TiDB. Is it the same as the configuration approaches in MySQL? Besides using the `set` command, how to configure it using the configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of `sql_mode` in TiDB is a little different from that in MySQL. TiDB does not support configuring `sql_mode` using the configuration file.

In TiDB, you can modify `sql_mode` using the `set` command as follows: `set @@global.sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';`.